# Instead of violation of unique key need to show proper message

Tags: c#, validation, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQ, if the Club Name and tournament name are the same, my code should not allow the data to be inserted.

When I tried to insert duplicate data, I get an error

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint IX_BBMatchRegistration
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object dbo BBMatchRegistration
>   The duplicate key value

I want to show message like your team is already registered like that.

Comment: **WHAT** database is this for? What programming language are you using to access this database??

Comment: SQL server r2 and C# language

Comment: try...catch... log exception, show friendly message to the user. Simple.